# How many passengers can be booked under a single Premium Tatkal ticket of Indian railways?

Tags: bookings, indian-railways, tatkal, irctc

How many passengers can be booked under a single ticket purchased using the [premium tatkal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatkal_scheme#Premium_Tatkal) scheme of Indian railways? Is it only two or more than two?

Answer (score 2):

Premium Tatkal is an e-ticket only service with dynamic pricing. [This document](http://www.services.irctc.co.in/betadoc/salient%20features%20of%20pt%20quota.pdf) describes its salient features. Summary (emphasis mine):

> - Advance Reservation Period (ARP) of Premium Tatkal  ticket booking is same as Tatkal ticket  booking.
> - Agents will not be allowed to book tickets in this  quota.
> - Dynamic fare shall be charged for confirm passenger s.
> - RAC/ Waitlist Ticket Booking is not allowed.
> - Only E-tickets will be permitted for booking.
> - I-ticket Booking is not allowed with this Quota.
> - No concession shall be applicable in this Quota.
> - Child passenger will be charged with full fare.
> - **All rules for tatkal quota booking over internet is  applicable to Premium Tatkal quota also.**

If we lookup the [Tatkal Guide](https://www.services.irctc.co.in/beta_htmls/TatkalBookingGuide.htm), it explicilty states

> Maximum of **four passengers** per PNR can be booked on Tatkal e-tickets.

Thus it is reasonable to assume that **maximum four passengers can be booked under a single Premium Tatkal ticket** too. This is borne out by the fact that booking screen has only 4 entries when choosing a premium tatkal option

[image: Premium Tatkal booking screen]